# Dragging-Swapping-Dropping in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have 4 objects movieClips (Suppose Card1, Card2, Card3, Card4).

Card4 is on top and covering some part of Card3, same as Card3 is covering some part of Card2, and Card2 is covering some part of Card1.

Now what I want to do that whenever I drag Card4 on Card3. so, here Card4 should have to taken same position or depth of card3 how it was before. 
And card3 should have to take Card4 Position means on top how Card4 was before.

How can I achieve this? This is my mouse down event. Here board is my container where I put my all cards display objects.

```
function CardDraging(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.startDrag();
    currentCard = event.target as DisplayObject;
    board.setChildIndex(currentCard, board.numChildren-1);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add condition: If current card is a Card4 and it hitTest Card3, then...

```
if (currentCard == Card4 && currentCard.hitTestObject(Card3))
{
    // If Card3 under Card4, then move Card3 to top.
    if (getChildIndex(Card3) < getChildIndex(Card4))
        swapChildren(Card3, Card4);
}
```

UPDATE 1:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDown);

var currentCard: MovieClip;

function mouseDown(event: MouseEvent): void
{
    currentCard = event.target as MovieClip;
    currentCard.startDrag();

    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMove);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUp);
}

function mouseMove(event: MouseEvent): void
{
    if (currentCard.hitTestObject(Card1))
    {
        if (getChildIndex(Card1) < getChildIndex(currentCard))
            swapChildren(Card1, currentCard);
    }
    else if (currentCard.hitTestObject(Card2))
    {
        if (getChildIndex(Card2) < getChildIndex(currentCard))
            swapChildren(Card2, currentCard);
    }
    else if (currentCard.hitTestObject(Card3))
    {
        if (getChildIndex(Card3) < getChildIndex(currentCard))
            swapChildren(Card3, currentCard);
    }
    else if (currentCard.hitTestObject(Card4))
    {
        if (getChildIndex(Card4) < getChildIndex(currentCard))
            swapChildren(Card4, currentCard);
    }

    event.updateAfterEvent();
}

function mouseUp(event: MouseEvent): void
{
    currentCard.stopDrag();
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMove);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUp);
}
```

UPDATE 2:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDown);

var currentCard: MovieClip;

function mouseDown(event: MouseEvent): void
{
    currentCard = event.target as MovieClip;
    currentCard.startDrag();

    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMove);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUp);
    mouseMove(event);
}

function mouseMove(event: MouseEvent): void
{
    if (currentCard != Card1 && currentCard.hitTestObject(Card1))
    {
        if (getChildIndex(Card1) < getChildIndex(currentCard))
            swapChildren(Card1, currentCard);
    }

    if (currentCard != Card2 && currentCard.hitTestObject(Card2))
    {
        if (getChildIndex(Card2) < getChildIndex(currentCard))
            swapChildren(Card2, currentCard);
    }

    if (currentCard != Card3 && currentCard.hitTestObject(Card3))
    {
        if (getChildIndex(Card3) < getChildIndex(currentCard))
            swapChildren(Card3, currentCard);
    }

    if (currentCard != Card4 && currentCard.hitTestObject(Card4))
    {
        if (getChildIndex(Card4) < getChildIndex(currentCard))
            swapChildren(Card4, currentCard);
    }

    event.updateAfterEvent();
}

function mouseUp(event: MouseEvent): void
{
    currentCard.stopDrag();
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMove);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUp);
}
```

Comment: Yes..swapChildren is the solution...but now on mouse move event how can i achive dynamically HitTestObject as movieclip! because may be my movieclip should be on each other in case with same cordinates.

Comment: @Dnyanesh I updated my answer. I posted all my code. Try to use it.

Comment: @Dnyanesh I don't understand what you want to do. The `currentCard` should be placed under of all Cards?

Comment: @Dnyanesh Updated again. Try my 2-nd code. If `currentCard` will be under another object, the `currentCard` will be underneath.